# Root with no permission to work with psql

Tags: permissions, psql

I need to use root user to run scripts at crontab, for example to read and write on all `/home` folders.
But something that I need to do also in the shell script is to run `psql`. Problem:

- *my user* (me = `whoami` and not is root) can run for example `psql -c "\l"`
- the *root user* not works (!) with `psql -c "\l"`... And error not make sense 
  *"psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "root" does not exist"*.

How to enable root to run `psql`?

---

PS: looking for a kind of "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL DATABASES TO root".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root` *is* allowed to run `psql`, but nobody can connect to a database that doesn't exist.

The default value for the database user name with `psql` is the operating system user name, and the default for the database is the same as the database user name.

So you have to specify the correct database and database user explicitly:

```sh
psql -U postgres -d postgres -l
```

The next thing you are going to complain about is that peer authentication was denied.

To avoid that, either run as operating system user `postgres` or change the rules in `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: Thanks, `psql -U postgres -l` is running (!) with user root.  On my shell with user john `psql -l` works fine, but there are no database  john, not works with `psql john` or `psql -d john`... same for root.  The `psql -c "etc"` works fine with both, root's `psql -U postgres -c "etc"` and and john's `psql -c "etc"`. So I not agree that "you have to specify the correct database user explicitly"

Comment: My `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` have line `local   all             postgres                                peer    map=superuser`

Comment: I said that "the default for the database is the same as the database user name", so if you use `-U postgres`, the database will default to `postgres`.

Comment: Hi, the phrase doesn't make sense for  john's `psql -c "etc"`, because it is not the same as `psql john -c "etc"`, the database **is not the user name**.

Comment: If you have a problem parsing my English, read up on it in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), where it is explained in all desirable detail.

Comment: Sorry Laurenz, English is not my native language and, now I see, at my terminal tests all tested users (like *john* example) has an exotic configuration (e. g. are in the *postgres* user group at Linux and all have RULE LOGIN at *postgres* database)... My comments only make sense for that users, where "default database" is *postgres*... Now tested with standad Linux user and your instructions make sense.